# in Rstudio keras library what is ggplot2 code to generate history plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, keras, plot

**tl;dr**
What is the R code that takes the keras history form and produces not the tensorflow/keras plot shown below but the ggplot shown slightly farther below?

**Details:**
Rstudio has a wrapper for keras:
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/

When training a model, it displays a plot of the loss and metrics over time.  I think it is using plotly.  I am not interested in the graph that has these stylings.

[image]

You can take the history object an plot it again, and it generates a new plot.  If you have 'ggplot2' installed, then it uses ggplot.

I am looking for something like this, the product of ggplot2:

[image]

What is the R code that takes the keras history form and produces that ggplot?
I am not looking for the wrapper which is 'plot(history)', but the set of frame manipulations and input commands to ggplot that generate the output.  It should contain something of the form'ggplot(history, aes(...)) + ...'

Comment: See `keras:::plot.keras_training_history`. Note that is uses `keras:::as.data.frame.keras_training_history` to prepare the data.

Comment: You'll find that the code is a bit of a hack. I wrote it to minimize package dependencies, and so it fakes the two panels by using facets and some theme adjustments.

Comment: @Axeman - I was feeling guilty about using melt and I figured the authors had something elegant in there.  :)